# CountIF in different Sheet and equal values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

[image]

[image]

Scenario:

I Want to Count the Values of Sheet 2 (Lower Image) Column C into Sheet 1 Column C, IF the values of Sheet 2 Columns A and B is equal to Sheet 1 Columns A and B.

this is without using excel-vba,

thanks,

Comment: That's an amazing idea. :) which formula have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `COUNTIFS()` for this.

Comment: Should in Sheet 1 Column C stand in every line a 1 for the requirements are met and a 0 for not or should there be a equal value in all 4 cells about the count of all 4 farmers?

Comment: like for C2: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2)`???

Comment: I have tried CountIF formulas, a lot, but it seems it wont work, I also tried CountIF + Vlookup, still doesnt work, maybe someone can answer this.

Comment: I think Dirk Reichel answer is correct, ill just test it on multiple data,

Comment: I get it, so @DirkReichel focused the countif on columns A & B instead on C, thanks for the idea

Comment: if that satify your task, then I am glad I could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Comment @Dirk Reichel has offered:

```
 =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2)
```

which it seems may have been acceptable to the OP. This makes (IMO the very reasonable) assumption that there will always be a value in the `FarmerID` field in Sheet 2. However OP has not specified that there will be and for the sake of those with the same issue that may have blanks I suggest a third condition to exclude those from the count:

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet 2'!A:A,A2,'Sheet 2'!B:B,B2,'Sheet 2'!C:C,"<>"&"")
```